# How to achieve an incrementing concatenated values for id

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel app, when a user submits a new order, I have set an order-id column in my table to be a concatenation of the date, user Id of the authenticated user and a counter that starts from 1 in my controller like so;

```
$date = date ('ymd');
$user = Auth::id ();
$count = 1;

$order = new Order;
$order->order-id = $date. $user. $count;
$order->save ();
$count++;
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is that the first time a user with user id 90 makes an order (on 1st July for example) the order Id is `180701090001` (180701 as date, 090 as user Id and 001 as counter)  & when he makes the next order say on 3rd July, I should get an order-id of `180703090002`. However, what I keep getting presently is `180701090001`. How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try getting the latest saved order and then add a plus one to that order id

```
$order = DB::table('orders')->order_by('id', 'desc')->first();
$order_id = $order->order_id + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @luis.i thought there's a function that could be used to generate an incrementing value maybe in the order model or controller, & then while creating a new transaction,this function is called  and the value is concatenated to the date and user Id variables

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get an idea from this.

```
echo '<pre>';
class Order
{
    #######################
    # It would be better to separate the database incrementing id  and the transction id for the order
    #######################

    public $id;
    public $transaciton_id;

    /**
     * Set the incrementing id when the object is instantiated and also set the transaction id for this order
     */
    public function __construct($lastid,$user_id)
    {
        $this->id=$lastid+1;  
        $this->set_transaction_id($user_id); 
    }

    /**
     * Set the transaction id
     * 
     */
    private function set_transaction_id($user_id)
    {
        $date = date ('ymd');
        $this->transaciton_id=$date.sprintf("%03d",$user_id).sprintf("%03d",$this->id);
    }
}
$user_id=90;//user id

//array of orders
$orders=[];

//adding new orders
$orders[]=new Order(count($orders),$user_id);
$orders[]=new Order(count($orders),$user_id);
$orders[]=new Order(count($orders),$user_id);
$orders[]=new Order(count($orders),$user_id);
$orders[]=new Order(count($orders),$user_id);

print_r($orders);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Order Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [transaciton_id] => 180702090001
        )

    [1] => Order Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [transaciton_id] => 180702090002
        )

    [2] => Order Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [transaciton_id] => 180702090003
        )

    [3] => Order Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [transaciton_id] => 180702090004
        )

    [4] => Order Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [transaciton_id] => 180702090005
        )

)
```

UPDATE:

in order to get the last inserted id of the model maybe you can do it this way. It may not the best answer but you can get the same result.

```
public static function model_last_id($model)
{
    $example_model=$model::orderBy('id','desc')->First();
    if($example_model!=null)
        return $example_model->id;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kelvin.Please could you explain how the $lastid in the public function construct is gotten?

Comment: the $lastid is just an example but if you are referring to the model/table on how we can get the last_id then there are a lot of ways to do it, you can use raw query to get the last inserted id or you can check the model it self the last inserted data and get the id of it.

i have updated my comment above for the last id